# Trigger event on div's content which has event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have div with event click on it to do something on click, and that div contain list of items, each item has an event too.
What I'm trying to do is that trigger only the event for the clicked item, not both item and it's container's event. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pnxx9h3/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>action 1</li>
        <li>action 2</li>
        <li>action 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

$('.container').click(function(){
   var x = document.getElementById('result');
    $(x).append(' container clicked');
});

$('.container ul').on('click','li',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var x = document.getElementById('result');
    $(x).append(' li clicked');
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `e.stopPropagation()`

```
$('.container ul').on('click','li',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var x = document.getElementById('result');
    $(x).append(' li clicked');
});
```

`e.preventDefault();` can disappear as there's no default action to suppress.

And I expect you want to do this :

```
$('.container ul').on('click','li',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#result").append(this);//move the clicked LI element to the container #result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('.container ul').on('click','li',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    var x = document.getElementById('result');
    $(x).append(' li clicked');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3pnxx9h3/3/)